# Issue with Python data-mining code from "Programming Collective Intelligence" to count crossed lines

Tags: python, data-mining

I'm currently working through Toby Segaran's Programming Collective Intelligence and trying to do work through some of the code in the optimisation chapter, specifically the counting lines code. However I have come across two issues in the code which I don't quite understand. 
The code

```
def crosscount(v):


loc = dict([(people[i],(v[i*2],v[i*2+1])) for i in range(0, len(people))])
total = 0

for i in range(len(links)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(links)):
        (x1,y1), (x2,y2) = loc[links[i][0]],loc[links[i][1]]
        (x3,y3), (x4, y4)= loc[links[j][0]],loc[links[j][1]]

        den = (y4-y3)*(x2-x1)-(x4-x3)*(y2-y1)

        if den == 0: continue
```

Initially I got the error 'list index out of range' for the line where the loc dictionary is defined where the v[i*2] is defined which I assume is because v is a random number generated rather than a list.

To get it sort of working so that I can try to follow the logic, I changed it to v*2 to generate the pairs of integers but throws an error in the line where den is calculated with 'unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list''. I've tried putting the (x1, y1) et al as lists and then slicing it but I still get the same result and casting to int() has not worked unless I cast the value to a string first (which seems very un-Pythonic). I'd be grateful for some advice on how to get this code working so that I can see what is supposed to be happening in calculating the crossed lines.

Comment: The indentation is broken, this code definitely won't compile as written.  Also, it's hard to answer this question when we don't know what datatype are `links` and `people`.

Comment: two much ranges...why not `for link in links`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ipe, i read this book, I searched trought my test codes and I found how it worked for me, the graph score function follows:

```
def graphscore(v, proxlimit = 50):
loc = dict([(people[i], (v[i*2], v[i*2+1])) for i in range(0, len(people))])
total = 0.0

#penalize crosscount
for i in range(len(links)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(links)):
        (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = loc[links[i][0]], loc[links[i][1]]
        (x3, y3), (x4, y4) = loc[links[j][0]], loc[links[j][1]]

        den = (y4-y3)*(x2-x1)-(x4-x3)*(y2-y1)
        if den==0: continue #lines parallel

        ua = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3)-(y4-y3)*(x1-x3))/float(den)
        ub = ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3)-(y2-y1)*(x1-x3))/float(den)
        if ua > 0 and ua < 1 and ub > 0 and ub < 1:
            total += 1.0

#penalize tightened nodes
for i in range(len(people)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(people)):
        (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = loc[people[i]], loc[people[j]]
        dist = math.sqrt(math.pow(x1-x2, 2) + math.pow(y1-y2, 2))
        if dist < proxlimit:
            total += (1.0-(dist/proxlimit))
return total
```

where the following globals are declared at the beginning of the file ( of course ):

```
people = ['Charlie', 'Augustus', 'Veruca', 'Violet',
         'Mike', 'Joe', 'Willy', 'Miranda']
links = [('Augustus', 'Willy'),
        ('Mike', 'Joe'),
        ('Miranda', 'Mike'),
        ('Violet', 'Augustus'),
        ('Miranda', 'Willy'),
        ('Charlie', 'Mike'),
        ('Veruca', 'Joe'),
        ('Miranda', 'Augustus'),
        ('Willy', 'Augustus'),
        ('Joe', 'Charlie'),
        ('Veruca', 'Augustus'),
        ('Miranda', 'Joe')]
```